# How to display only one key value in autocomplete.js even if the entered value matches other fields also

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete.js (https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/). The keys used are 'username and email'. When user enters values as 'pre', all names starting with matched parameters are displayed in autocomplete textbox. But how to display the username of people even if the parameter 'pre' matches the email also.

Note: Only username column needs to be displayed which matches either the username or email

How to change the filter to match the above criteria:

```
 keys: ["username", "Email"],
            cache: false,
            filter: (list) => {
     
                const filteredResults = Array.from(
                    new Set(list.map((value) => value.match))
                ).map((x) => {

                    return list.find((value) => value.match === x);
                });
                            
                return filteredResults;
            }
        },
```

Note: On adding keys - username, email.. duplicate records with username and email are shown

Answer (score 0):

```
keys: ["username", "Email"],
        cache: false,
        filter: (list) => {
            var resultArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (resultArray.length <= 0 && list[i].value.Email != 'null') {
                    resultArray.push(list[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                var alreadyAdded = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < resultArray.length; j++) {
                    if (resultArray[j].value.Email == list[i].value.Email) {
                        alreadyAdded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!alreadyAdded && list[i].value.Email != 'null') { resultArray.push(list[i]); }

            }
            return resultArray;
        }
```